# Is there a way to solve $\partial_{\bar{z}}f=g$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, complex-integration

If $g$ is a regular (not necessarily holomorphic) function, $g:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$, is there a way to find a complex function $f$ such that 
$$
\partial_{\bar{z}}f=g\quad\text{in }\mathbb{C}
$$
where $\partial_{\bar{z}}=\partial_x+i\partial_y$? I suspect that the only way is to transform it into a system of first order real differential equations but maybe there is a more clever way I don't know about. Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Integrate it like you normally would, by considering $z$ and $\bar{z}$ to be independent variables. For example, if $g = |z|^2 = z\bar{z}$ then one such $f$ would be $\frac{1}{2}z\bar{z}^2$. Though of course, this is mod a holomorphic function. This is also only true if you use $\partial_{\bar{z}} \equiv \frac{1}{2}\left(\partial_x + i \partial_y\right)$, otherwise there is that factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ to consider. This convention (with the factor) has its benefits over the other (without), namely allowing this integration trick to work with normal calculus rules.

Comment: This is just "$\overline{\partial}$ Poincare lemma in one variable.